# Why won't IE implement my CSS rules instantly?

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer

I'm having difficulties with Internet Explorer (even as up-to-date as IE11). I'm trying to write some JavaScript that will allow me to dynamically create a style sheet, add it to the document and manipulate styles, most of which is based on the article that [David Walsh wrote](http://davidwalsh.name/add-rules-stylesheets). He had the idea of setting the `media` attribute of the created `style` tag so legacy browsers will simply ignore rules that they can't support - an idea that I really like, but one that's causing me a few problems.

When I create a `style` tag with a `media` attribute more complicated than `"screen"`, Firefox and Chrome will apply the new rules instantly (assuming the media query matches), but IE will not until some kind of page repaint is triggered (resizing the page seems the most effective).

I've created a [fiddle to better demonstrate the issue](http://jsfiddle.net/Skateside/rLLAF/). I'm seeing the results panel having a green background in Firefox and Chrome but red in IE until the repaint is forced.
As for actually forcing a repaint, I've tried a few tricks to no success:

- `document.body.className = document.body.className;`
- `element.appendChild(document.createTextNode(' '));`
- `document.body.style.width = (previousWidth + 1) + 'px'`
- Simplifying the media query to `all and (min-width: 10px)` and even just `(min-width: 10px)`

My question is "**How can I get IE to implement the styles when they're added?**" (or at least, as close to the time their added a possible, I can live with a `setTimeout` being needed)

I'm using jQuery on the site itself so I'll accept a jQuery answer, but I'd prefer one without a library dependancy so I better understand what's causing the issue and how to resolve it.

Comment: +1 for actually constructing a good question, it's so rare these days!

Comment: I do see a green bg in IE? IE9 and IE10, can't test IE11.

Comment: When I test your script in jsFiddle and offline, IE11 is showing a warning for XSS and blocked content. So i guess the problem could be caused by browser security. See this update http://jsfiddle.net/rLLAF/10/ when you press run in IE11 with open console you should see the same error. I just appened a `console.log(this.media.screen);` within line 102. Like i said this is not a problem caused by jsFiddle, this is also happening when you download everything and put in one html file.

Comment: @DieterGoetelen Since you mentioned that, I fired up a VM with IE10 and sure enough, the background is green. I wonder if this is a regression for IE11? I'll try again in IE9 in a VM and possibly update the question

Comment: @NicoO curiously, I'm not seeing that XSS issue even in your fiddle. I wonder if one of us has a strange setting in IE11?

Comment: @NicoO 's fiddle doesn't error for me in IE11

Comment: @JamesLong you are right. I had IE restarted several times before commeting, but now the error won't reprocude here two. I've default settings for IE. I've experiemented a lot and at some point, usually using `alert` or `console.log` IE would throw a XSS security warning. I will try to make a "solid" version to reproduce.

Comment: that is too strange... Just so you belive me, here is the screenshot i can reproduce by now: http://oi57.tinypic.com/6p9ukz.jpg but when i close IE and reopen the same source the error is gone. Since it don't appear to happen, when you don't alter the source it maybe has nothing to do with the actual question. To sorry to have confused you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you disable line 65 of the javascript it appears to work:

```
// Webkit hack.
// element.appendChild(document.createTextNode(''));
```

Since this is apparently a hack, perhaps it can be removed, or worked around more elegantly.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rLLAF/37/)

Comment: When I saw the phrase "Webkit hack" in the original article, I never thought to question why the hack existed in the first place. I can't even find any information online about it and removing it fixes my issue without breaking Chrome or Safari. Thank you ^_^

Comment: A pleasure.  Might be worth letting the original author know about this.

Comment: I thought so too. I've added a comment to the article to let him know. Since the article's only a year old, there's possibly a version of Safari still floating around that would need the hack. I'll see if he or his readers say anything.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding `<!DOCTYPE>` ? I don't know about the scenario you are facing, but for style issue in IE `<!DOCTYPE>` solved my problem. It says the Browser about the HTML version you are using so that the browser can render your view exactly what you needed. For HTML5 it is simple `<!DOCTYPE html>` . You will find the list of all doctype [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>

   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yeah, that's the DOCTYPE I'm using. No joy. Thanks though.